# Windows 7 touch screen - disabling multi-touch gesture not working

Tags: windows, touchscreen, controlpanel

I have a touch screen computer with Windows 7 and I would like to disable the multi-touch gesture :

[image]

But even if I disable it and apply the changes, when I reopen the window, the option is enabled again...

Any idea where I can disable it for good ? (maybe in the registry...)

Up: still have the problem.

Answer (score 5):

How to disable "multi-touch gestures and inking"

1. Run \Windows\System32\regedt32 as Administrator
2. Navigate to HKEY_USERS
3. Find entry that starts with S-1-5-21-xxxxxxxx
4. Note there might be a few GUIDS that starts with S-1-5-21.
   You need the one that you can drill to
   S-1-5-21xx\Software\Microsoft\Wisp
5. Under Wisp key there should be keys like Pen, Touch,
   to indicate you are in the right location
6. Under Wisp key add additional key MultiTouch
7. Go inside MultiTouch key and create DWORD
   MultiTouchEnabled set to 0
8. Reboot

Comment: The main problem is that the "MultiTouch" key is missing. Once it is added, the option from the control panel works. However, you can set setting within the registry as described by whizza, of course.

Comment: Why are you in `HKCU`? Do it in the `HKLM`.