# Disable default touch gestures in Js and Html

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm making a small HTML canvas application in HTML and JS, and ran into a problem with touch gestures.

I am working on allowing users to draw on a canvas with a touch screen. After adding support for multi touch I realized that the default touch gestures, such as scrolling or zooming, are still active.

I need to disable the default touch gestures for the entire page.

My first idea was to use `Event.preventDefault()` but it gives off an error and solves nothing.

Then I found this HTML attribute `content="user-scalable=no"` but that didn't work either.

So now I'm a bit stumped and would love some advice.

Answer (score 1):

I know that you mentioned using `event.preventDefault()`, but it is a little confusing that this did not work for you, as it is the recommended way to do something like this.

Try this:

```
window.ontouchstart = function(event) {
    if (event.touches.length>1) { //If there is more than one touch
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

It does the following:

1. Runs whenever the user begins touching their device's screen (`ontouchstart`).
2. The function is given the `event` variable, which contains details about the event, including an array called `touches` with information about each touch in it. This array has an item for each place the screen is being pressed, so by getting it's length (`event.touches.length`) we get how many fingers the user is using - obviously we do not want to cancel single presses, as otherwise the user will not be able to do *anything*.
3. Finally, we call `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the default actions caused by these events. You could also implement your own custom actions above the `event.preventDefault` line.

For further information, you can take a look at [this StackOverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37379694/javascript-how-to-stop-pinch-zoom-multi-touch-input-attacks).

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out. the `event.preventDefault()` doesnt work at all but using `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">` this i got it to work properly. the issue was that i was using that attribute in my canvas instead of the meta so i had `<canvas id="canvas" width="2000" height="2000" content="user-scalable=no">`. thanks either way.

Edit: nope still not working. I was debugging on my pc with the chrome tools but seems to have had no effect on an actual touchscreen

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the css property for any element whose touch gestures you want to remove.

Set the css property `touch-action: none;`

Keep in mind that doing this will disable all the browser supported touch gestures such as zoom in, zoom out, etc.