# Chrome ignores "user-scalable=no" meta tag

Tags: html

Why **desktop-chrome** ignores this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
```

I can resize chrome content with **windows-touch** and also **ctrl+mouse-wheel**.
I want to prevent zooming.

---

**Chrome:** Version 65.0.3325.146 (Official Build) (32-bit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to **[the Google Map documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics)**,

> Android and iOS devices respect the following `<meta>` tag:
>
> `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />`
>
> This setting specifies that the map should be displayed full-screen and should not be resizable by the user. Note that the iPhone's Safari browser requires this  tag be included within the page's  element.

Desktop computers do not respect the `user-scalable` attribute, though mobiles will.

If you want to prevent zoom in Chrome on **desktop** computers, your best bet would be to enable kiosk mode with the following startup arguments:

```
chrome.exe --kiosk --incognito --disable-pinch --overscroll-history-navigation=0
```

Comment: Ok, so i cannot use the meta-tag to force it in desktop; but also i cannot tell the user to use a complex Command.

Comment: Ok, infact your answer helped me a lot about another question i had in my mind, Thanks :) i add some parameters to your answer and changed it like this **"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app=http://www.stackoverflow.com --windows-size=800,600 --kiosk --incognito --disable-pinch --overscroll-history-navigation=0** the incognito mode working but zooming still enable !

Comment: Hello Obsidian!, I am trying to execute chrome as you said, with the --disable-pinch --overscroll-history-navigation=0 flags in command line but it does not work at all. I am using Chrome Versión 73.0.3683.75. It does not forbid the overscroll gestures.... I am about to go crazy....:|. Any help is sooo welcome. Thanks!