# How to disable page zoom in chrome

Tags: html, css

How to disable page zoom in my code? I mean zooming like this:

[image]

**Note**: I only want it to work in chrome.

Here is the code:

```css
*{
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container {

   overflow: hidden;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.number-ticker {
  position:absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  color: #D9D9D9;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: Roboto Light;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 1.1em;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.number-ticker .digit {
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  line-height: 1;
  transition: margin-top 0.75s ease-in-out;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Number Ticker</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="number-ticker.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="number-ticker" data-value="10"></div>
        </div>

        <script src="number-ticker.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have used these in HTML head with no success...

```
<meta 
     name='viewport' 
     content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' 
/>
```

and this one:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

But unfortunately, it still zooms... !!!  Am I missing something?

I have seen pages that don't zoom at all... So I know there should be a working way ...

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116221/prevent-zoom-cross-browser it gives some insight on ways to prevent users from zooming in on different browsers

Comment: None of the codes work...

Comment: Try to take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49541173/how-to-prevent-default-handling-of-touch-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who may encounter this annoying problem. you only need to use `vh` and `vw` in all of your sizes  (fonts, elements, etc...) instead of `px` and `em`.... those units do not follow page zoom!

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem before, too, and I think Chrome ignores "user-scalable=no" (at least on desktops).

Check out this answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49371150/12343443