# Disabling Multi Touch on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, multi-touch

On Windows 10 I am unable to find the option to disable Multi touch. As also seen here http://support.intuilab.com/kb/how-to/properly-configure-windows-pc-touch-and-gesture-behaviors there is no "Enable multi-touch gestures and inking" checkbox.

I have also tried the solution from [Windows 7 touch screen - disabling multi-touch gesture not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886188/windows-7-touch-screen-disabling-multi-touch-gesture-not-working/27233353#27233353) but that doesn't seem to work under Windows 10.

The idea is to use application that supports only mouse input with touch screen that provides multi-touch.