# Disable pinch zoom and multi touch gestures in windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, touchscreen, pinchzoom

I hooked up a `LG 23ET63` multi-touch monitor to my windows pc `Windows 10` looking to run a site on Chrome in kiosk mode.

But currently I have facing some problems trying to disable pinch zooming on every browser I've tried.

I've tried the following but none of them worked.

1- Added this to my html

```
<meta name="viewport" ccontent="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"">
```

2- Edited the regedit as mentioned in the following solution:
[Windows 7 touch screen - disabling multi-touch gesture not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886188/windows-7-touch-screen-disabling-multi-touch-gesture-not-working)

And theres alot of sites out there outlining steps to disable multi touch on touchpads but not for touchscreen.

I believe its definitely a Windows 10 thing, because ive tried 2 different touch monitors, both on windows and mac, but only on windows 10 does the zoom issue occur.

So I'm looking for a solution for windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Make a shortcut leading to `chrome.exe`, add the url followed by `--kiosk` and `--disable-pinch`

example:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" www.theurl.se --kiosk --disable-pinch
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the driver from the Touch screen manufacturer of your touch screen brand only that should works properly. Other drivers will take you for a ride